# R: data.table : searching on multiple columns AND setting data type

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

Q1:

Is it possible for me to search on two different columns in a data table. I have a 2 million odd row data and I want to have the option to search on either of the two columns. One has names and other has integers.

Example:

```
x <- data.table(foo=letters,bar=1:length(letters))
x

want to do
x['c'] : searching on foo column
as well as 
x[2]   : searching on bar column
```

Q2:
Is it possible to change the default data types in a data table. I am reading in a matrix with both character and integer columns however everything is being read in as a character.

Thanks!
-Abhi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your Q2 first, a `data.table` is a `data.frame`, both of which are internally a `list`. Each column of the `data.table` (or `data.frame`) can therefore be of a different class. But you can't do that with a `matrix`. You can use `:=` to change the class (by reference - no unnecessary copy being made), for example, of "bar" here:

```
x[, bar := as.integer(as.character(bar))]
```

For Q1, if you want to use fast subset (using binary search) feature of `data.table`, then you've to *set key*, using the function `setkey`.

```
setkey(x, foo)
```

allows you to fast-subset on 'x' alone like: `x['a']` (or `x[J('a')]`). Similarly setting a key on 'bar' allows you to fast-subset on that column.

If you set the key on both 'foo' and 'bar' then you can provide values for both like so:

```
setkey(x) # or alternatively setkey(x, foo, bar)
x[J('c', 3)]
```

However, this'll subset those where x == 'c' **and** y == 3. Currently, I don't think there is a way to do a `|` operation with fast-subset directly. You'll have to resort to a vector-scan approach in that case.

Hope this is what your question was about. Not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix is already a character. Matrices hold only one data type. You can try `X['c']` and `X[J(2)]`. You can change data types as `X[,col := as.character(col)]`